# Open Main Window in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, view

I am new to WPF and am building a WPF MVVM application.

I can't seem to figure out how to open the main window in my app.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
    x:Class="First.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    DispatcherUnhandledException="OnDispatcherUnhandledException"
    Startup="OnStartup" />
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var appLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);

    //configure host

    await _host.StartAsync();
}
```

I need to add `MainView` as the main window.

**MainView.xaml.cs**

```
public MainView(MainViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Since I have a parameterized constructor, injecting the ViewModel (via dependency injection) and setting the `DataContext` to it, I can't simply add

```
MainView mainView = new MainView();
MainView.Show();
```

in the `OnStartUp` method in `App.xaml.cs`, as it needs a parameter.

What is the best approach to open the window?

I have tried using `StartupUri="MainView.xaml"` in `App.xaml`, but I need the `OnStartup` method to configure the services and so on.

Comment: Why do you need that parameterized constructor? DataContext is a public property that could be set at any time after creating the view.

Comment: @Clemens Where else can I set it?

Comment: No idea. We don't know how and when a MainViewModel instance is created. As soon as you have a view model instance, assign it to the MainView's DataContext.

Comment: I guess this will solve my issue, thanks!

Comment: @Clemens The problem is that I am not instantiating MainViewModel anywhere, I am searching for all the occurrences of MainViewModel in my code and there is only one else - `services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();`. The other one was the constructor injection and setting of the DataContext in MainView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try again to understand dependency injection I guess. Also when using an IoC container you also want to apply the *Dependency Inversion* principle. Otherwise dependency injection is very useless and only overcomplicates your code.

You must retrieve the composed instance from the IoC container. In your case, it seems you are using the .NET Core dependency injection framework. In general, the pattern is the same for every IoC framework: 1) register dependencies 2) compose the dependency graph 3) get the startup view from the container and show it 4) dispose the container (handle lifecycle - don't pass it around!):

**App.xaml.cs**

```
private async void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  var services = new ServiceCollection();
  services.AddSingleton<MainViewModel>();
  services.AddSingleton<MainView>();
  await using ServiceProvider container = services.BuildServiceProvider();

  // Let the container compose and export the MainView
  var mainWindow = container.GetService<MainView>();

  // Launch the main view
  mainWindow.Show();
}
```